# input type image not working

Tags: django, forms

so, i'm working on this Django website and i'm done with i18n translations and now i'm trying to set the language switcher form as flags but the code isn't working!

the select/option/submit works perfectly BUT the code with input type image doesen't work, it submits, reloads the page, but the language isn't changed!

any ideas?

```
    <div id="lang">
        <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{request.path}}" />

            {%for lang in LANGUAGES %}
            <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{lang.0}}"/>
            <input id="lang_{{lang.0}}" type="image" 
            src="static/img/flags/{{ lang.0 }}.png" alt="{{ lang.1 }}"/>
            {% endfor %}

            <select name="language">
            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
            <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Go" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you without seeing the view function responsible for changing the language...

Answer (score 0):

You form is messed up with two things.

Multiple element has same `name` attribute

```
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{lang.0}}"/>
<select name="language">
```

Form element with no `name` attribute.

```
<input id="lang_{{lang.0}}" type="image" 
            src="static/img/flags/{{ lang.0 }}.png" alt="{{ lang.1 }}"/>|
```

How you are trying to get the values in regarding view?

Comment: i actually solved it already! i put the entire form inside the for loop, thus creating one form for each language and flag, which is actually the most correct way of doing it i believe, since each form will post and request a different language...don't how i didn't realize something so silly before!